# JavaScript String Separator

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Guys I have the following code which delete the white spaces before and after some separators and insert a separator after another separator(,).I want to add third separator(\n new line) and when the code find the separator to insert a new line.

```
 var newSeparators = /\s*([.!:?])\s*|\s*(,)\s*/g;
    textToTransform = textToTransform.replace(newSeparators, function($0, $1, $2) {
      return $2 ?  $2 + " " :  $1 ;
    });
```

Comment: does it work? do you have some data to test? and the wanted results? and what is the question?

Comment: Yes it works I said that I want to add a new separator to 'newSeparators'  variable (the \n separator) and when it finds that separator to let a new line in the text.The problem is that this code deletes my new line after the $2

Comment: can you give an example for `textToTransform` ?

Comment: Well, `\s` matches a newline. You seem to want to avoid that, right? Replace `\s` with `[^\S\n]`.

Comment: replace all \s with [^\S\n]?

Comment: Yes, all `\s` with `[^\S\n]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks agains for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since the `\s` pattern matches any whitespace, it also matches a newline. You need to exclude `\n` from `\s`. A simple way to do it is to use a reverse negated character class, `[^\S]`, and add an exception there - `[^\S\n]`.

Use

```
/[^\S\n]*([.!:?])[^\S\n]*|[^\S\n]*(,)[^\S\n]*/g
```